# Restore deleted email with OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client

Tags: c#, pop3, openpop

Accidentally I removed few emails with `Pop3Client` from email

I use [OpenPop](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/) for .net email parsing

In the mail client deleted emails disappeared

Trash is empty, synchronise with server nothing change.

Any proposal how I can to restore this emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The POP3 protocol does not handle `deleted emails` in any way. You need to look at your email provider, and see if you can restore your email from there somehow.

If the provider does not provide a way to restore the email, and you cannot get it in any other way, I guess the email is lost.